# Compatibility of "column as alias" vs "alias = column"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've found that over the years my habits have changed and I much prefer writing queries like this:

`select FriendlyName = some_column from some_table`

as opposed to this:

`select some_column as FriendlyName from some_table`

Lately I've been reviewing scripts written by some SQL experts which were designed to work across multiple database versions and platforms and I only ever see the latter syntax.

This was never a concern for me before as a software developer knowing specifically what version of SQL Server my code would be run on, but now I'm writing code that I would like to make as accessible to as many versions/platforms as possible. At least, I'd like to write it so the least amount of modifications are necessary to run on additional versions when the time comes.

That said, my question is whether the former syntax (`alias = some_column`) has always been part of the SQL specification and will run on any database, or would it not work in some platforms or older versions?

Comment: You should simply try the `=` syntax on your database of interest.  AFAIK, I have only ever seen this syntax of alias on SQL Server.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `Friendly_Name = expression` for [readability reasons](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases), even though it's proprietary - I have the luxury of only caring about SQL Server. If you want code that works across multiple platforms, sure, you want to stay away from it, but switching and/or supporting other platforms is not that common in my 2+ decades of experience. And would involve changing or avoiding a lot of other proprietary SQL Server stuff, too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed. I had in mind some scripts like sp_Blitz though, and so now I understand why they wouldn't use that syntax if it only works with SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have convenient access to older versions of SQL Server nor to Oracle, PostGre, or MySQL. I think installing them all to find out through experience versus asking an easily answered question here isn't really a reasonable request. And, call me lazy if you like, but I also feel it's a reasonable question to ask over having to read through SQL Specifications as well considering it could be a well supported feature of all rdbms's even if not in the official specs (I now know it's not, but I couldn't have known that from the specs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alias =` syntax is specific to SQL Server.  The standard is either:

```
<expression> as alias
<expression> alias
```

That is, the `as` is optional -- although I strongly encourage using it.

It is a shame that you have adapted to a syntax that is not available in other databases, and can actually mean other things.  In most other databases that accept the syntax, it will be interpreted as a boolean comparison -- and often generate an error because `alias` is not defined.

And, unfortunately, this syntax convention makes it harder to SQL Server to support a real boolean type, which would be a convenience.

Comment: This answer is `as` good `as` the best I have seen today +1.

Comment: At this point I don't think my using it or not is going to affect SQL Server supporting a real boolean type. Most the work I do is strictly for use in SQL Server and I feel the `=` syntax looks much nicer and cleaner. So I don't experience any of the downsides you mention but I will obviously stick to `as` syntax for anything that could be used on multiple platforms. Actually, don't hate me, but I like to leave out the `as` also when I use that syntax :D. For me it's just white noise that I don't need to see.

Comment: @BVernon . . . Unfortunately, `as` is not white noise when you get used to it.  Just wait til you leave out a comma in an `insert . . . select` and have a real hard time figuring out why the query is not returning the right number of columns.  The `as` doesn't solve this problem, but when you get used to seeing it, the missing comma is more obvious.